# How to define a class with just one constructor with body in kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, constructor

I want to define a class with just one constructor with body . When i set parameter of class i can't define the body of primary constructor.
I want the class have only one constructor.

Foe example

I  have a class that extends CursorWrapper. This class have parameter that need to superclass implementation. I need a constructor with one parameter that do it:

```
class wrapper(cursoe: Cursor): CursoreWrapper {
    // i need to call super(cursor). But where?
}
```

Comment: Your question is a little hard to assist, to me you are describing a symptom of the issue you’re having. Could you provide more context of what and why? Are you familiar with https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to call cursor, it means your `CursorWrapper` (clearly typo here) is at least an abstract class, and not an interface.

Judging by your question, it also receives `cursor` (another typo) as an argument, so we get something like this:

```
open class CursorWrapper(cursor: Cursor)
```

Now, to invoke this constructor, you simply call it when you inherit from the class:

```
class Wrapper(cursor: Cursor): CursorWrapper(cursor) // <- this is your super(cursor)
```

Now let's assume that you also have another function on `CursorWrapper` that you need to call during construction.

```
open class CursorWrapper(cursor: Cursor) {
    fun bla() { 
       // You want to call this for some reason as super.bla()
    }
}
```

You can use `init()` block for that.

```
class Wrapper(cursor: Cursor): CursorWrapper(cursor) {
    // i need to call super(cursor). But where?
    init {
        super.bla()
    }
}
```